# How does Chrome detect language in local HTML files?

Tags: google-chrome, privacy

I just opened a local HTML file on my disk in Google Chrome. Chrome detected the language the file is in and asked me whether I want to translate it.

The document has no `lang` attribute. It contains some Hungarian text, Chrome offers translation from Hungarian.

Here is a small file that causes Chrome to offer translation dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Tudományegyetem
</body>
</html>
```

I think this is weird. Does the Chrome send my local files to google for language detection?

**EDIT** OK, now we have a truly minimal file. I deleted "Eötvös Loránd" (a Hungarian name), and kept a single Hungarian word, that means "[university](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_Lor%C3%A1nd_Tudom%C3%A1nyegyetem)". There is a single accented char in the page now, namely "á" -- [Unicode U+00E1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E1) (I use UTF-8 locally). This character is not unique to Hungarian language; it is [used in many languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81). Chrome still detects Hungarian language.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To give an answer we would need to see this HTML file.

Comment: Well, at least the `<head>` part.  You can change domain information to mask it if you like.

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes, it does. Wow, a neural network! Amazing.  Yes, I believe it is possible to recognize that a word  like that is Hungarian.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the HTML page language can be determined by checking the `lang` HTML attribute.
You can find an additional information here: [Declaring language in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)

> [The lang attribute is a Global Attribute, and can be used on any HTML
> element.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_lang.asp)

---

For example, in the Google CHROME right click on the page and select `View Page Source`. In opened HTML page look up for something like `<html lang="en"`: in my case it was English. If no language specified the default language English is used.

Therefore, there is no need to send a file to the server to determine the language.

Comment: I have added a small example in the question.